# Build artifact retention setting being ignored

Tags: azure-devops

I had a build be deleted from the retain policy and I want to increase the retain policy time.

I go to project settings->pipelines->settings and it says

'The artifacts and attachments retention setting is being ignored because the runs retention setting is evaluated first.'

and it won't let me change the 'days to keep artifacts and attachments'

I can't seem to find where this setting is...

I've looked under project settings -> Test -> Retention but I'm not sure that's the place.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Build artifact retention setting being ignored

This behavior is **by designed** and is not a issue.

As we know, the artifacts and attachments are generated from the pipeline runs. If the build pipeline is deleted, the artifacts and attachments it generates will also be deleted.

That the reason why you set the value of `Days to keep artifacts and attachments` **greater than or equal** to the value of `Days to keep runs`, you will get that prompt:

[image]

When you set the value of `Number of days to keep artifacts and attachments` **less than** the value of `Days to keep runs`, that warning will disappear:

[image]

**So**, if you want to increase the retain policy time for Build artifact, you need increase the retain time for `Days to keep runs`.

> it won't let me change the 'days to keep artifacts and attachments'

That because you don't have enough permissions, to change the Retention policy, you must be a member of the **Project Collection Administrators Group**.

Check the document [Set permissions at the project- or collection-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#prerequisites) for some more details.

Or you can ask someone in the PCA to change the Retention policy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering this, other places (like the documentation, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4953) aren't clear what is required.

Additionally, this is IMO too restrictive. A collection administrator should delegate this to a project administrator.